# pacemaker pending tasks list

Tags: cluster-computing, crm, high-availability, pacemaker

Does anyone know how to get list of pending tasks in linux HA cluster with pacemaker/openais?

Suppose I have a 2-node cluster with both nodes in online state. I add nodeB into standby state and then stop the pacemaker/openais services on it.

Then, I accidentally executed using crm: "crm node online nodeB".
As soon as pacemaker/openais service is started on nodeB, the node instead of remaining in standby state, changes its state to online.

I want to know if we can view such pending actions/tasks and is there a way to undo/remove them?